# Obtaining the equation of the straight line projecting onto a given pixel in an image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to use Opencv with Python 2.7 to obtain world coordinate informations from images. I correctly performed the calibration of the camera (see description below), and obtained the camera pose in world coordinate, including the coordinates of the (virtual) pinhole of the camera. What I now need is a function f(pixel) which takes a pixel [x,y] of the image as an input argument, and returns the equation of the straight line (in world coordinates) that projects onto the given pixel (it is the same as finding the world coordinates of a point on the straight line, since I already have the coordinates of the pinhole). Help will be greatly appreciated. Below are the description of the steps I already performed:

EDIT:

1. This question may appear to be a duplicate, but it is a fact that I haven't seen a detailed solution of this problem in this forum.
2. If my understanding is good, the camera axes system is parallel to the axes of the image, and its third axis is pointing toward the view of the camera. So, it is clear that the problem amounts to the following question, interesting by itself:

Where is located the centre of the image with respect to the camera axes system (i.e need one translation vector), and what is the physical length of one pixel ?

STEPS PERFORMED:

Playing with a chess board in front of the camera, I first obtained the intrinsic parameters matrix, and the distortion parameters (see the tutorial in opencv-python):

```
(ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs) = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, grayImg.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

Then I obtained the camera pause (extrinsic parameter matrix) from one image of the chess board, using the following piece of code:

```
[ret, corners] = cv2.findChessboardCorners(grayImg, [7,7], None)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(grayImg, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
[ret, rvec, tvec] = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
Rmat = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0] #rotation matrix of the camera pause
cameraPinhole = np.dot(-Rmat.T, tvec) #location of the virtual pinhole of the camera with respect to world coordinates
```

Then I obtained the projection of the world coordinate axes (located at a corner of the chess board) on the image, and use them to plot theses axes on the image:

```
axes = chess_board_square_sz * np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)
[axes_proj,  jac] = cv2.projectPoints(axes, rvec, tvec, newcameramtx, dist)
img = draw_axes(img, corners2, axes_coor)
```

What should be the next steps ?

Comment: you only need 2 real world points. so use the camera center (= camera position) and the pixel location in real world. latter  can be computed by "inverting" the projection. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection for example

Comment: Thx. Actually, this is not an affine transformation, because of the distortion parameters. So, I would appreciate to know how to use the functions of opencv to do this task, at the level of the code.

Comment: it's just about matrix multiplication (which is a core feature of openCV) ;) but you should understand the math of how projection works.

Comment: @Micka How do you take into account the distortion parameters due to the lens ?

Comment: they're part of the formula (if you find the right formula). Or just use undistorted pixel positions.

Comment: maybe they're not part of the formula... just use the undistorted pixel positions :D